# How can I search an angularjs array with ng-repeat on the website

Tags: angularjs

I need some help with the following. When the value of array key ppkfound is true the website should show a certain text while when the value in the array key is not true.. it should display something else.

I've tried to do this with applying a filter and using the limitTo. This works as long as there is a product with a pkkfound value true. When the pkkfound value is false it wont showup.

How can I make this work because when I not apply this filter the total will be displayed several times (equals the numbers of lines in the array).

See code below.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in localStorage.items | filter:'true' | limitTo: 1">
  <span ng-hide="item.ppkfound == 'false'">&plusmn; {{totalBtw() | currency:"&euro;"}}</a></span>
  <span ng-hide="item.ppkfound != 'false'">{{totalBtw() | currency:"&euro;"}}</a></span>
</div>
```

What is the best way to fix this. In other parts of the webpage this logic works great as long as I not use the filter options.

In short i'm trying to search the array for any key with the value true (preferably only pkkfound key). If thats found he should put a ± in front of the total number only displaying it once.

Thanks for your help already!

Comment: Can you explain properly what you want to achieve? Here you are using a filter with true so ppkfound = true will only come in result. Result array inside ng-repeat will never have record with false.

Comment: That is exactly the problem. I wanna search the array and if the array, in all its lines, has a pkkfound = true it should display the &plusmn; sign. However when I try to loose the filter and limit it will display the totalBtw amount multiple times. So i'm kinda stuck on how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not use `ng-repeat` here. Its the [`ng-switch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) that you can use here.

Try this please.

```
<div ng-switch="(localStorage.items|filter:'true'|limitTo:1)[0].ppkfound">
    <span ng-switch-when="true"><a>&plusmn; {{totalBtw() | currency:"&euro;"}}</a></span>
    <span ng-switch-default><a>{{totalBtw() | currency:"&euro;"}}</a></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use Angulars `ng-if` directive for that.

```
<span ng-if="item.ppkfound == 'false'">&plusmn; {{totalBtw() | currency:"&euro;"}}</a></span>
<span ng-if="item.ppkfound != 'false'">{{totalBtw() | currency:"&euro;"}}</a></span>
```

If you do so, the expected element will be the only one being shown. With `ng-hide` you would create both elements and Angular would simply hide one of them while `ng-if` will only render the expected one.

Comment: Thanks Aer0 but without the filter option in ng-repeat it will display the totalBtw amount multiple times based on the number of lines in the array.

Comment: To be honest, I actually don't get what you want to achieve, since this would do the same as your way with hiding the elements. Is there any chance you could provide some more code? A fiddle would be cool so we could follow up your thoughts.